# How to add a list of values to a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

I want to add the list lst=[10, 20] element-wise to 'col1' to have the following dataframe.

```
    col1   col2
0     11     3
1     22     4
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to edit the column in-place you could do,

```
df['col1'] += lst
```

after which `df` will be,

```
    col1   col2
0     11     3
1     22     4
```

Similarly, other types of mathematical operations are possible, such as,

```
df['col1'] *= lst
df['col1'] /= lst
```

If you want to create a new dataframe after addition,

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1['col1'] = df['col1'].add(lst, axis=0) # df['col1'].add(lst) outputs a series, df['col1']+lst also works
```

Now `df1` is;

```
    col1   col2
0     11     3
1     22     4
```